# How to configure ranger to open pdf files with Foxit Reader

Tags: filemanager, xterm, foxitreader

I've made an alias to the program in my .bashrc file as can be seen below:

```
alias foxitreader="/home/username/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader"
```

And I've made the following entry in my rifle.conf file at the top of the list for pdf readers:

```
ext pdf, has foxitreader, X, flag f = foxitreader "$@"
```

Despite this, the pdf files do not open via Foxit but instead with Okular.  However, if I type the following in the terminal the file does open without any issues:

```
foxitreader myfile.pdf
```

Please advise how I can achieve the desired result.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2 and using XTerm terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what aliases are designed for. Instead of filling in the alias in your config file, try filling in a real command. This is either the full path name to the executable, or a symlink to it or a script that calls it. Let us go for a symlink.

If you want to launch FoxitReader without having to type in the full path name, create a symlink to the FoxitReader executable in a folder that is in your PATH. In Ubuntu, a folder `~/bin` (a folder called `bin` in your home folder) automatically will be added to your path if it exists. So if you do not yet have a `bin` folder in your home folder, then create one:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Then create a symlink to your executable into that folder:

```
ln -s  /home/username/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader ~/bin/foxitreader
```

Now you can launch FoxitReader simply by typing the command `foxitreader`. In addition, your `rifle.conf` config file should now work.

Comment: It turns out the there was already a symlink to the executable in the `bin` folder. I replaced the alias with the symlink in `rifle.conf`, and it works now.

Comment: Indeed, an installation program would normally also install an executable in the path, either a symlink or a wrapper script or a binary. However, you could have installed Foxreader by placing the program files yourself under /opt, and then these "finishing touches" (a command in the path, a .desktop file, ...) also would have been manual work.